# How to print all the facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am a beginner and I am using SWI Prolog  to write a rule to print all the facts about addition of two numbers.The following is the code:

```
addition(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X+Y.
add(X,Y):-
   between(X,Y,A),
   addition(X,A,Z),
   writeln(addition(X,A,Z)),
   X1 is X+1,
   add(X1,Y).
```

And the following is the output:

```
1 ?- add(1,2).
addition(1,1,2)
addition(2,2,4)
addition(1,2,3)
addition(2,2,4)
false.
```

As you can see the output addition(2,2,4) is repeating and addition(2,1,3) is missing. What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Avoid using side-effects like `writeln` in the beginning.

Comment: What exactly should be the meaning of `add/2`? It is not very clear from the predicate you have written or your description.

Answer (score 1):

`addition/3` is a "rule", or a "predicate", not a fact. Anyway, you have defined it as:

```
% addition(X, Y, Z)
% Z is the sum of the integers X and Y
```

Now you want to apply this predicate to (and I am guessing here) each pair X and Y such that X is between A and B and Y is between A and B:

```
% add(A, B, Addition)
% Add all numbers X and Y that are between A and B
add(A, B, addition(X, Y, Z)) :-
    between(A, B, X),
    between(A, B, Y),
    addition(X, Y, Z).
```

You will notice that you don't need recursion (or iteration): you can use the fact that `between/3` is non-deterministic and will create choice points that will be evaluated on backtracking.

You can now call it like this:

```
?- add(1, 2, A).
A = addition(1, 1, 2) ;
A = addition(1, 2, 3) ;
A = addition(2, 1, 3) ;
A = addition(2, 2, 4).
```

You can press the `;` or space to backtrack and evaluate the next solution.

The third argument to `add/3` is unified with the **term** `addition/3` in the head of `add/3`. It happens to have the same name as the predicate `addition/3`, but it could have been called anything.

If you insist on printing it out from a single call, you could use `forall/2`:

```
?- forall(add(1, 2, A), format('~q', [A])).
```